# cambiar icono marker con menu contextual

Tags: android

estoy desarrollando una aplicion en android estudio.
Tengo en un mapa con varios marcadores que genere como muestro en la imagen, al hacer click en el inforwindows me sale un menu contextual con varias opciones lo que necesito es al hacer escoger una opcion el markador donde estoy pocicionado se cambie de icono osea si escojo entregado quiero que el markador se cambie a Verde y asi depende de la opcion que escojo se cambie de color.

[image: Mapa con varios markadores]

Este es el codigo que estoy utilizando

```
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    String id = "";
    id = TituloGlobal.substring(0, TituloGlobal.indexOf(" -"));
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.meEntregado:
            guardarDatosCliente(id, "0", "3");


            break;
        case R.id.meParcial:
            guardarDatosCliente(id, "2", "4");
            mMap.

            break;
        case R.id.meCTotal:
            guardarDatosCliente(id, "1", "4");
            break;
        case R.id.meNPlata:
            guardarDatosCliente(id, "1", "5");
            break;
        case R.id.meRParcial:
            guardarDatosCliente(id, "2", "5");
            break;
        case R.id.meNSalio:
            guardarDatosCliente(id, "3", "5");
            break;
        case R.id.meNalcanzar:
            guardarDatosCliente(id, "4", "5");
            break;
    }


    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Soy nuevo es este lenguaje de programacion, espero puedam ayudarme y gracias de antemano.

```
package com.example.framac.app_framac;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.RedirectException;
import static android.R.attr.breadCrumbTitle;
import static android.R.attr.mode;
public class MostrarMapa extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    public String TituloGlobal, pList ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mostrar_mapa);
        to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        pList = extras.getString("PLIST");
        ObtDatos(pList);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {

        }

        googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                return false;
            }
        });

googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                TituloGlobal = marker.getTitle();
                registerForContextMenu(findViewById(R.id.map));
                openContextMenu(findViewById(R.id.map));

            }
        });

googleMap.setOnInfoWindowCloseListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowCloseListener()  {

            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClose(Marker marker) {


            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_mapa, menu);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        String id = "";
        id = TituloGlobal.substring(0, TituloGlobal.indexOf(" -"));
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.meEntregado:
                guardarDatosCliente(id, "0", "3");

                //setMarkerDrawableEjecucion("funcion", R.drawable.entregado);
                break;
            case R.id.meParcial:
                guardarDatosCliente(id, "2", "4");


                break;
            case R.id.meCTotal:
                guardarDatosCliente(id, "1", "4");
                break;
            case R.id.meNPlata:
                guardarDatosCliente(id, "1", "5");
                break;
            case R.id.meRParcial:
                guardarDatosCliente(id, "2", "5");
                break;
            case R.id.meNSalio:
                guardarDatosCliente(id, "3", "5");
                break;
            case R.id.meNalcanzar:
                guardarDatosCliente(id, "4", "5");
                break;
        }


        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    public Bitmap setMarkerDrawable(String dato) {
        int background = R.drawable.textonegocio;
String datoC = "";
        if (dato.length() > 25){
            datoC = dato.substring(0, 25);
        }else{
            datoC = dato;
        }

        Bitmap icon = drawTextToBitmap(background, String.valueOf(datoC));

        return icon;
    }

    public Bitmap setMarkerDrawable2(String dato) {
        int background = R.drawable.textocasa;

      String datoC = "";



        if (dato.length() > 25){
            datoC = dato.substring(0, 25);

        }else{
            datoC = dato;
        }

        Bitmap icon = drawTextToBitmap(background, String.valueOf(datoC));

        return icon;
    }

    public Bitmap drawTextToBitmap(int gResId, String gText) {

        Resources resources = getResources();
        float scale = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, gResId);
        android.graphics.Bitmap.Config bitmapConfig = bitmap.getConfig();

        if (bitmapConfig == null) {
            bitmapConfig = android.graphics.Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        }
        bitmap = bitmap.copy(bitmapConfig, true);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
        paint.setTextSize((int) (8 * scale));
        paint.setShadowLayer(1f, 0f, 1f, Color.BLACK);
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        paint.getTextBounds(gText, 0, gText.length(), bounds);
        int x = (bitmap.getWidth() - bounds.width()) / 2;
        int y = (bitmap.getHeight() + bounds.height()) / 2;
        canvas.drawText(gText, x, y-15, paint);

        return bitmap;
    }


    public void CargarLista(ArrayList<String> datos) {
        double lat = 0, lon = 0, latD = 0, lonD = 0;
        String CodigoCliente = "", NombreCliente = "", RefCliente = "", telefonos = "", Op = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < datos.size(); i++) {
            String dato = datos.get(i).toString();

            try {
                CodigoCliente = String.valueOf(dato.substring(0, dato.indexOf("@")));
                NombreCliente = String.valueOf(dato.substring(dato.indexOf("@") + 1, dato.indexOf("$")));
                lat = Float.valueOf(dato.substring(dato.indexOf("$") + 1, dato.indexOf("%")));
                lon = Float.valueOf(dato.substring(dato.indexOf("%") + 1, dato.indexOf("&")));
                //RefCliente = String.valueOf(dato.substring(dato.indexOf("&") + 1, dato.indexOf("*")));
                telefonos = String.valueOf(dato.substring(dato.indexOf("&") + 1, dato.indexOf("#")));
                Op = String.valueOf(dato.substring(dato.indexOf("#") + 1, dato.length()));

                //datos.get(0).equals("false")
                if (Op.equals("1")) {
                    Marker marcador = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(lat, lon))
                            .title(String.valueOf(NombreCliente))
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(setMarkerDrawable(NombreCliente)))
                            .snippet(RefCliente + " Cel: " + telefonos)

                    );

                }

                if (Op.equals("2")) {
                    Marker marcador = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(lat, lon))
                            .title(String.valueOf(NombreCliente))
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(setMarkerDrawable2(NombreCliente)))
                            .snippet(RefCliente + " Cel: " + telefonos)
                    );


                }


            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException excepcion) {
                lat = 0;
                lon = 0;

            }
            if ((lat != 0) && (lon != 0)) {
                latD = lat;
                lonD = lon;

            }
            //marcador.showInfoWindow();
        }
        CameraPosition camPos = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(latD, lonD))   //Centramos el mapa en Madrid
                .zoom(15)         //Establecemos el zoom en 19
                .bearing(45)      //Establecemos la orientación con el noreste arriba
                .build();

        CameraUpdate camUpd3 =
                CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(camPos);
        mMap.animateCamera(camUpd3);

    }


    public void ObtDatos(String codigo){
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        String url = "http://www.framac.com.bo/webservice/pListBuscarE.php";

        RequestParams parametros = new RequestParams();
        //parametros.put("codigo", 131);

        parametros.put ("codigo", codigo);
        //parametros.put ("dia", 2);

        client.post(url, parametros, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                if (statusCode == 200){
                    CargarLista(ObtDatosJason(new String (responseBody)));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

            }
        });

    }

    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marcador) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Info window clicked",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> ObtDatosJason(String response){
        ArrayList<String> listado = new ArrayList<String>();
        try{
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
            String texto;
            for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                texto = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("codigo")+ '@'+
                        jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("cliente")+ '$'+
                        jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("latitud")+ '%'+
                        jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("longitud") + '&' +
                        //jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("referencia") + '*' +
                        jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("telefonos") + '#' +
                        jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("entrega");


                listado.add(texto);
            }


        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return  listado;
    }

    public void guardarDatosCliente(String cod, String op, String Entrega ) {

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        String url = "http://www.framac.com.bo/webservice/guardarDatosPlist.php";

        RequestParams parametros = new RequestParams();


        parametros.put("id", cod);
        parametros.put("opcion", op);
        parametros.put("entrega", Entrega);
        parametros.put("Lat", "0");
        parametros.put("Lon", "0");


        client.post(url, parametros, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Los datos se guardaron correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    toast1.show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Existe error en la coneccion con el servidor intente mas tarde", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast1.show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void cambiarIcono(Marker marker){
        //marker.
        marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
    }
}
```

Este es todo el codigo de mi aplicacion

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas para hacer cambiar el marcador de color es la siguiente linea

```
marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
```

donde HUE_BLUE es uno de los colores que puedes utilizar. La lista la puedes ver [aca](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/BitmapDescriptorFactory) y market es la instancia el marcador que utilizaste para ese marcador en especifico.

Para guardar la referencia del marcador, puedes crear un arreglo con todos los marcadores una vez los agregas al mapa, algo asi:

```
private ArrayList<Marker> mMarcadores;

mMarcadores.add(mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()....);
```

Puedes usar el `setOnMarkerClickListener`, y ahi es donde puedes recibir el marcador que estas utilizando. Por lo que pones en los comentarios, estas utilizando el `setOnInfoWindowClickListener` que es diferente.

Luego a tu funcion openContextMenu, no se como esta implementada, asi que no puedo ayudar mucho ahi pero puedes recibir el marcador, elegir la opcion y luego cambiar el color

```
mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(marker -> {
    openContextMenu(findViewById(R.id.map), marker);
    return false;
});

openContextMenu(MapView mapa,Marker marker){
    //etc lanzar dialogo
    //cachar opcion del dialogo
    marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
                    return false;
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por responder,

Comment: pero yo utilizo imagenes para generar los iconos <br> Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, gResId);
        android.graphics.Bitmap.Config bitmapConfig = bitmap.getConfig(); <br> el problema que tengo es como puedo acceder al markador con el que estoy trabajando, desde el menu contextual y cambiar ese markador con otra imagen que tengo guardada

Comment: en el markerclick puedes obtener el mercador que clickeas, asi en el metodo abres el menu y cambias la imagen

Comment: el menu contextual tiene varias opciones, y el color del marker dependera de la cual seleccione el usuario  [pre] googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

                TituloGlobal = marker.getTitle();
                registerForContextMenu(findViewById(R.id.map));
                openContextMenu(findViewById(R.id.map));
                cambiarIcono(marker);
            }

           }); [codigo] se ejecuta los openContextMenu y al mismo tiempo cambiar icono

Comment: como puedo mandar el marker al metodo openContextMenu, de menera que esta programado en este momento funciona pero cuando hago click en el infowindows se ejecuta al mismo tiempo los dos procedimientos y se cambia el icono, pero yo necesito que se cambie el icono cuando seleccione una opcion y no antes

Comment: @Marcelo, agregue mas a mi respuesta, a ver que te parece

Comment: Con esta solucion, cambia el icono pero ya ne me aparece el menu <code>registerForContextMenu(findViewById(R.id.map));
                openContextMenu(findViewById(R.id.map));</code>, no son clases definidas de Activiti.class, la defini como me los mencionas y ya no me muestra el menu

Comment: si puedes agrega tu codigo en tu pregunta para poder verlo con mas claridad, tu funcion openContextMenu , registerForContextMenu y cambiarIcono

Comment: ya agregue todo el codigo de mi aplicacion